The operation couldn't be completed (-10814) when trying to push visionOS SDK app
When I try to push my visionOS SDK built app to a device from XCode (using 15.3) I get "The operation couldn't be completed (OSStatus -10814)" and it asks me to trust the dev cert. However when I go to the menu in my Vision Pro I don't see any cert to accept. I have gotten this error on two separate environments with two separate physical devices.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Here's the first error I get in the console logs that seems related, though I can't figure out what it means:

default 13:02:13.325727-0700 installcoordination_proxy
-[IXAppInstallCoordinator setPlaceholderDisposition:error:]_block_invoke: Failed to set
placeholder disposition to Delete Placeholder on
<IXInitiatingAppInstallCoordinator<0x896806bf0>
identity:[[REDACTED][REDACTED]] uuid:[REDACTED]
creator:InstallCoordination Proxy> : Error Domain=IXErrorDomain
Code=25 "Client installcoordination_proxy (pid 470) is missing
entitlement to set placeholder disposition."
UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Client not entitled.,
FunctionName=-[IXSClientConnection
_remote_IXSCoordinatedAppInstall:setPlaceholderDisposition:completion:],
SourceFileLine=1964, NSLocalizedDescription=Client
installcoordination_proxy (pid 470) is missing entitlement to set
placeholder disposition.} error 13:02:13.325757-0700
installcoordination_proxy

